# import ca and crt file to android studio

Tags: android-studio, https, socket.io

I have .crt and .ca file. I try to paste to res/raw file and make a socket from socket.io. Purpose for https. What can I do next if start with empty project android studio ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself and my way:

- Code again follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQgbxOY3lIo
- And:

  ```
      HostnameVerifier myHostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
          @Override
          public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
              HostnameVerifier hv =
                      HttpsURLConnection.getDefaultHostnameVerifier();
              return hv.verify("example.com", session);
          }
      };
     OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
     .hostnameVerifier(myHostnameVerifier)
     .sslSocketFactory(mySSLContext.getSocketFactory(), myX509TrustManager)
     .build();    
     // default settings for all sockets
     IO.setDefaultOkHttpWebSocketFactory(okHttpClient);
     IO.setDefaultOkHttpCallFactory(okHttpClient);        
     // set as an option
     opts = new IO.Options();
     opts.callFactory = okHttpClient;
     opts.webSocketFactory = okHttpClient;
     socket = IO.socket("https://example.com", opts);
  ```

inside connect() below `context.init(null,tmf.getTrustManagers(),null);` 
and ofcouse `InputStream caInput = getAssets().open("yourca.crt");` with not self signed ssl. That's it. Hope it make this forum best-er, it's too cold!